# Relevance of a character name in Dan Simmons' Olympos

Tags: dan-simmons, ilium-olympos

In Dan Simmons' novel *Olympos*, a character called Moira is also referred to as 'Moneta' (chapter 56). Is this a throwaway line, a reference to the character of the same name in the Hyperion series, or is there a classical link that I'm overlooking?

Comment: "Moira" is itself a name of some significance. The Moirai or Moirae were incarnations of destiny, synonymous with the Three Fates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moirai

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Moneta* is not a name but a Latin [epithet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moneta).  It was applied to more than one goddess, but most commonly to Juno, the most important Roman goddess in imperial times and the protectress of civic Rome.  (It is from Juno's associations with the Roman treasury, which she protected, that we get the word *money*.)  The ultimate Latin etymology of *moneta* is unclear; it may be a merger of two different words, with meanings related to warning and uniqueness.

As an epithet of the most powerful Roman goddess, *Moneta* could used simply as a term of high respect, although it is probably also an allusion to the character from Dan Simmons' earlier *Hyperion Cantos* novels.  However, his use of the name *Moneta* in the *Hyperian Cantos* was itself presumably an allusion to the character of Moneta in John Keats' poem "[The Fall of Hyperion—A Dream](http://www.john-keats.com/gedichte/the_fall_of_hyperion.htm)," in which she is the last priestess of the long-forgotten god Saturn, mourning for the passing of his greatness.